# Необходимость одноразовых функций в программе

Tags: функции, любой-язык

Хочу спросить, какой смысл в использовании функции в программе, если она вызывается один раз? Возможно, *эстетический*, для понятности кода?
Спасибо!

Comment: Ответ зависит от само́й функции

Comment: @andreymal Не "функции", а "ф-и"! :p

Comment: Я считаю, что подобный вопрос вполне может иметь конкретные ответы - поэтому голосую за переоткрытие. И ответы уже дали вполне конкретные, не породив бесконечных дискуссий и прений, так что пусть живёт.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. **Разделение ответственности.** Функция имеет некое предназначение и оно отделяется от того, что с ним не связано. Например, даже если строку надо привести в верхнему регистру всего один раз, то логично сделать отдельную функцию, которая именно это и делает, а не смешивать её с вводом и выводом этой строки. В момент, когда эта функция понадобится снова, её не придётся копипастить или выносить - она уже будет.
2. **Чистые функции** позволяют запоминать результат вызова в случае, если аргументы не меняются. Да и в другой проект их перенести куда проще. Поэтому может иметь смысл отделять функцию-преобразование от побочных эффектов.
3. **Лямбда-функции** передаются в другие функции как аргументы, например `a.sort((x,y) => x-y)`. Сама лямбда-функция и так является функцией, но некоторые языки их не поддерживают и приходится писать самостоятельные функции.
4. **Упрощение потока кода.** Когда из функции выносятся некие участки кода, и её становится проце читать. Например, `var height = isFlexible ? calcFlexibleHeight() : calcHeight();`, а каждая из вычисляющих функций по 100 строк - получится гораздо удобнее,  чем огромный if-else с переменной перед ним. Но тут главное не перестараться - при разбивании на совсем маленькие участки код действительно можно читать как книгу, но вот отлаживать его - это ад.
5. **Изолировать область видимости.** В некоторых языках скоупом для переменных является функция. Если нужно создать область видимости, то придётся создавать и функцию.
6. **Функция `main`**, которая вызывается автоматически при запуске программы.
7. **Реализации членов интерфейса** - тут уж никуда не деться, если по какой-то причине есть интерфейс и его нельзя менять, то придётся реализовывать.

Answer (score 3):

Для начала надо разобраться что такое функция.
Давайте обратимся к источнику "знаний":

> Функция в программировании — фрагмент программного кода
>   (**подпрограмма**), к которому можно обратиться из другого места
>   программы.

Теперь будет чисто отсебятина, ключевое в этом тексте(лично для меня) - что функция это подпрограмма, т.е. часть программы **выполняющая осмысленное законченное действие**.

Если судить исходя из этого - есть смысл выделять в функции все участки кода которые сами по себе выполняют некое конечное действие. Допустим даже если нам нужно подсчитать сумму двух векторов в программе всего один раз - будет **хорошим тоном выделить** это в **отдельную функцию.**

Далее выделение частей кода в осмысленные функции - улучшает читаемость кода, даже если функция вызывается один раз.

Это не полный набор плюсов, но минусов(при правильной реализации) очень мало в современных реалиях.
Дабы совсем о них не умолчать приведу два известных мне:

- Небольшой оверхед на перескок(call)
- Накладные расходы на сохранение\восстановление стека.

p.s. Небольшое дополнение - многие современные ЯП умеют определять "оптимальность" выноса кода в функцию и в итоге в скомпилированном виде - вызов функции заменяется на вставку этого кода в место вызова. т.е. в исходниках у вас функция, а в бинарнике - функции как бы и нету.